# What is the difference between Pytorch's DataParallel and DistributedDataParallel?

Tags: gpu, distributed, pytorch

I am going through [this imagenet example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py).

And, in [line 88](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/86bc3e516dde92fee0ce00668a3714c03155dd44/imagenet/main.py#L88), the module DistributedDataParallel is used. When I searched for the same in the [docs](http://pytorch.org/docs/), I haven’t found anything. However, I found the [documentation for `DataParallel`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html?highlight=dataparallel#dataparallel-layers-multi-gpu-distributed).

So, would like to know what is the difference between the DataParallel and DistributedDataParallel modules.

Comment: well, by docs I think they are totally same. Aren't they?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the Distributed GPUs functionality is only a couple of days old [in the v2.0 release version of Pytorch], there is still no documentation regarding that. So, I had to go through the source code's docstrings for figuring out the difference. So, the docstring of the `DistributedDataParallel` module is as follows:

> Implements distributed data parallelism at the module level.
>       This container parallelizes the application of the given module by
>       splitting the input across the specified devices by chunking in the batch
>       dimension. The module is **replicated on each machine and each device**, and
>       each such replica handles a portion of the input. During the backwards
>       pass, gradients from each node are averaged.
>       The batch size should be larger than the number of GPUs used locally. It
>       should also be an integer multiple of the number of GPUs so that each chunk
>       is the same size (so that each GPU processes the same number of samples).

And the docstring for the `dataparallel` is as follows:

> Implements data parallelism at the module level.
>       This container parallelizes the application of the given module by
>       splitting the input across the specified devices by chunking in the batch
>       dimension. In the forward pass, the module is replicated on each device,
>       and each replica handles a portion of the input. During the backwards
>       pass, gradients from each replica are summed into the original module.
>       The batch size should be larger than the number of GPUs used. It should
>       also be an integer multiple of the number of GPUs so that each chunk is the
>       same size (so that each GPU processes the same number of samples).

This [reply in the Pytorch forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-dataparallel-and-distributeddataparallel/6108/2?u=dawny33) was also helpful in understanding the difference between the both,

Comment: Why the gradients from each node are averaged instead of summed in DDP?

Answer (score 6):

`DataParallel` is easier to debug, because your training script is contained in one process. `DataParallel` may also cause poor GPU-utilization, because one master GPU must hold the model, combined loss, and combined gradients of all GPUs.

For a more detailed explanation, see [here](http://www.telesens.co/2019/04/04/distributed-data-parallel-training-using-pytorch-on-aws/).